# Loading a PartialView via ajax does not load dropdownlist selected item correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This example is contrived, I have a partial view that i load via ajax on a page.  There is a dropdownlist on the partial view.  If a I change the value of the dropdownlist and then in the controller i reset the value.  When the partial view loads again(via ajax), the dropdownlist does not get the set value correctly.

Loading partial view:

```
@model Test_PartailViews.Models.MyItemViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div id="partialViewGoesHere">  
</div>

@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetForm',
        type: 'GET',         
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
          $('#partialViewGoesHere').html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status + ':' + thrownError);
        }
      });
 });
 </script>
}
```

Partial View with dropdownlist

```
@model Test_PartailViews.Models.MyItemViewModel
 
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "HomeForm" }))
  {
    <fieldset>
      @Model.MyItemId
      <div class="row">      
        <div class="col-sm-4 editor-field">

          @Html.DropDownList("MyItemId", new SelectList(Model.ItemOptions, "Id", "Name", Model.MyItemId), "Select One...")
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyItemId)

        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
  }
 
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#HomeForm').submit(function () {
    
    $.ajax({
      url: this.action,
      type: this.method,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      cache: false,
      success: function (result) {
        // reload the partial view that is returned from post
        $('#HomeForm').parent().html(result);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // show error occured
        $('#HomeForm').parent().html(xhr.status + ':' + thrownError);
      }
    });

    // show loading image when ajax call is made
    $('#HomeForm').html('');
    
    return false;
  }); // $('form').submit

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
  {
   
    // Main page that has the partial view on it
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      MyItemViewModel model = new MyItemViewModel() { MyItemId = 1 };
      return View(model);
    }

    // return partial view
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetForm()
    {
      // reset the id to 1
      MyItemViewModel model = new MyItemViewModel() { MyItemId = 1 };
      return PartialView("_MyItemPV", model);
    }

    // save partial view data
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveForm(MyItemViewModel youModel)
    { 
       return GetForm();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyItemViewModel
  {

    public int MyItemId { get; set; }

    public List<MyItem> ItemOptions {
      get
      {
        List<MyItem> lst = new List<MyItem>();
        lst.Add(new MyItem() { Id = 1, Name = "One" });
        lst.Add(new MyItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" });
        lst.Add(new MyItem() { Id = 3, Name = "Three" });
        return lst;
      }
    }
    
  }

  public class MyItem
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

When the screen loads it shows the Id is 1 and dropdownlist is "One" as expected
[image: initial page load]

After changing the value to "Two" and clicking submit.  I would expect the GetForm method to reset the model value to 1, and the dropdownlist to read "One" as well.  However "Two" is selected, even though the Id is 1.
[image: Id is set to 1 but the dropdownlist has two selected]

After viewing the result from fiddler, i can confirm that the partial view is returning the value "two" as selected".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue before and clearing the ModelState in the controller did the trick for me. You could also just clear a particular value in the ModelState.

Comment: This answer is likely correct. The View will use the ModelBinders to set the values before it uses the model you passed through. This is *usually* what you want it to do, I.E. to preserve the user's inputs in case of an error, but sometimes it bites you. Clearing the ModelState will cause the view to use your viewmodel's values again.

Comment: While this will work, in general it should not be used (and clearing `ModelState` also clears validation errors as well). Instead follow the RPG pattern (the post method should be `return RedirectToAction("GetForm");`

Answer (score 0):

you are returning false in your javascript. here it is -

```
$('#HomeForm').html('');

return false;
```

this should be **return true**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I return false because i don't want to post the entire page, I just want to preform an ajax post on the form that is in the partial view.